# Collecting user information when there's no backend server (Landing Page)

Tags: javascript, github, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I usually set up simple landing pages on Github Pages, and they usually have a simple form that asks people to enter their names or emails. Since there's no backend, I usually just send an event to Google Analytics like below.

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
  ga.send('event', 'email', 'register', $('input').val())
})
```

It works ok for the most of the time but I don't like it because GA takes a day to load the full data. What I want is something that's lighter than setting up a backend server but better than using Google Analytics. I thought of storing it in Redis or MongoDB, but I thought it'd be insecure to expose API keys for DB on the frontend.

It really is an easy problem but I'm not sure what's the best way to do this. Does everyone really set up a backend server for every landing page?

Comment: Might help https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en

Comment: Here is a proof of concept for a solution that stores the data to a spreadsheet: http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/a-poor-mans-crm-with-ga-and-google-spreadsheets/

Answer (score 2):

By storing email addresses (which are personally identifiable information) in Google Analytics you violate Googles Terms of Service, so this should be a no-go for you.

An easy way out would be to use [Google Forms](https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/) to create a contact or registration form and have the results stored in a (Google) Spreadsheet, or you implement a function that stores data in a spreadsheet via [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) (here [is a gist with an example](https://gist.github.com/mhawksey/1276293), although it might need a little work to be brought up-to-date).

Comment: Thanks! if I used this method, does it mean anyone can use the script and decide to write to my Google Form?

Comment: Well yes (but then anyone can send data to the form action in any form, so that's not special to this solution).

Comment: @MaximusS Yeah, you REALLY shouldn't be violating Google Analytics' Terms of Service; I recommend you stop doing that as soon as possible. In fact, I'm surprised that they haven't stopped you already.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using https://zapier.com/ webhook integration with google sheets (is an easy way to do it). Please check https://zapier.com/zapbook/zaps/1035/add-data-to-a-spreadsheet-from-a-webhook/

if you only want the email... an alternative could be a contact form using some transactional email service like Elastic email an then download the contact list (you can use something like https://app.haboob.co to do an easy integration with your  landing)

hope it helps